# What is the difference/similarirty between P() and P[] in the discussion of Probability Theory?

Tags: probability

Do Parentheses and Square Brackets mean the same things in the discussion of Probability Theory?

For example, are P(X=0) and P[X=0] mean same things?

Do they have other uses?

Comment: There is absolutely no difference. It is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

They mean the same thing. ....